# SQLite3 SELECT WHERE Clause Help

Tags: sqlite

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "feeds" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
"md5"   varchar(32),
"title" varchar(255));
CREATE INDEX "index_feeds_on_md5" ON "feeds" ("md5");
```

When I run: `select id, title, md5 from feeds WHERE feeds.title = 'Authors Audio';`

It returns:

```
id|title|md5
99|Authors Audio|5db86b5899889e0ea49b0ab7ff6223f0
```

When I run: `select id, title, md5 from feeds WHERE feeds.md5 = '5db86b5899889e0ea49b0ab7ff6223f0';`

It returns nothing.

Why? <strike>Is the column name md5 a reserved word in SQLite3?</strike> According to: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html `md5` is not a reserved word in SQLite.

Comment: What ended up being the resolution?

Comment: To be honest I never did find the answer. So I just redesigned the table not to use the word md5. Then it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try back ticking the field names in your queries.

```
select `id`, `title`, `md5` from `feeds` WHERE `feeds`.`md5` = '5db86b5899889e0ea49b0ab7ff6223f0'
```

This will help distinguish your table structure so that you don't run into problems such as this.

Comment: Did not work unfortunately; same result. Also according to http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html md5 is not a reserved word. So I need to re-title this question.

Comment: In which client program are you executing this query? Some have trouble when the column name is fully qualified with the table name, e.g. feeds.md5

Comment: `$ sqlite3 --version` gave me `3.7.4`. Its an Ubuntu package: `3.7.4-2ubuntu5`